# How to implement my class mysqli_result

Tags: php, sql

I would like implement my class mysqli_result to replace all my *mysql_result deprecated*.

I already create my class :

```
class mysqli_result{

  private $res;
  private $row;
  private $field=0;

  private function __construct(){
      ;
  }

  static public function get($res,$row,$field){
      $res->data_seek($row); 
      $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
      return $datarow[$field]; 
  }
}
```

I implement this method like that

```
mysqli_result::get(...)
```

But I got a

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class mysqli_result

I have a require_once of the file where is my class, this is the problem ?

Comment: What's there in `__construct()` method?

Comment: No, it means that the class already exists and cannot be redeclared. Extend it instead.

Comment: The `;` change nothing guys ;)

Comment: try renaming that class then; might be a reserved class word

Comment: You see the error? It says that the class has been declared, therefor e you can not redeclare it. But you can implement a new class with your required functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There already is a class [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), unless you compiled PHP yourself and specifically disabled the mysqli extension.

You either need to choose a different name or define your class in a namespace:

```
<?php
namespace whatever; // Must be the first thing in the file!
class mysqli_result
{
    // ...
}
```